# Access non-persisted memory-mapped files

Tags: c++, linux, posix, mmap, memory-mapped-files

I cannot find a library for non-persisted memory-mapped files in Linux for C++. I searched for a while to find any library but there is nothing is there any reason why this does not exist in Linux and what would work instead of non-persisted memory-mapped files to share memory between two programs.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with "non-persisted memory-mapped files"? How do they differ from normal memory-mapping of files?

Comment: And you might want to take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially [what's on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (because asking for libraries isn't).

Comment: My question is why there is nothing for Linux but so much for windows.  non-persisted memory-mapped files are only in ram and do not  have a backup on your hard drive.

Comment: To me, that sound more like *shared memory* rather than memory-mapped files.

Comment: shared memory would be possible, but for my problem having it managed as a "file" has big advantages. for example, calling an image viewer with the file this is much harder with shared memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a library. This is directly supported by the POSIX standard.

Use `MAP_ANONYMOUS` on `mmap`:

> The mapping is not backed by any file; its contents are initialized to zero.